# the speed of a person drinking water and the benefits in variations

Tags: water, hydration

I woke up this morning after having a few drinks last night and felt particularly dehydrated.

Now, what I proceeded to do was drink a pint of water in, more or less, one go. I then went on to drink another pint at the same rate about 30 mins later. This resulted in me desperately needing to urinate soon after.

This made me think about the pros and cons about the speed at which I drank the water. My body obviously couldn't handle all that water in one go, so got rid of it. However, my body needed water and still did after the two pints of water. Therefore, what if I had slowly sipped the two pints of water over let's say 2 hours. Would my body have been able to use more volume of water from the amount I consumed?

In conclusion, is drinking water at a fast rate a waste of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you urinated a lot after drinking water, doesn't mean you drank too much.

The water dilates waste in your body, and flushes it out. One common reason for frequent urination is not always that you drank a lot of water, but that you have a lot of waste to flush out. So whatever water your body recieves, will be used for this purpose.

For the direct question; no. As long as you're not in a third-world country where water needs to be rationed, wasting water by drinking it is hardly ever a thing. Water has countless functions for our bodies, like energizing muscles, keeping your skin intact, the aforementioned waste transportation, maintaining bowel functions... The list goes on.

Keep in mind, just because you urinate or excrete something, doesn't mean you had too much of anything. It's just our very local garbage men doing their thing. And garbage pile-ups are inevitable in our bodies, just like they are in your kitchen.

Comment: I suppose you right Alec, water is readily available in this country. But what I was trying to get at is- would you body see it as a waste of resources if you didn't sip